# IE 9 is posting to facebook wall twice when like button is clicked and a comment is added to like

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-like

Stack:

Any idea what could be causing this? It seems like a IE ?9? problem. Basically, I'm using the XFBML facebook like button. And while I've been testing with it, I've noticed that if I "like something" and then write a comment in the like button popup that appears, the post appears on my facebook wall twice. It appears once looking like I just clicked "like" and didn't add a comment, then it appears again with the comment.

Any ideas as to how to fix this? I don't want IE users not liking my content out of fear that they will spam their facebook wall.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it actually makes sense that it would add one as `like` and the other as `comment` because it is divided up just like that!

To delve a little deeper, does this action vary between browsers, if so 1.) how and 2.) can you provide an example for us to see?